# SQL Trigger, sub query returning more then one value.

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I m having a trouble with my trigger, it works for single row update, but for multiple updates it gives error that sub query is returning more then one value. how to handle this.

```
    GO

    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OnpaymentUpdate]
       ON  [dbo].[paymentData]
     AFTER UPDATE 
    AS 
    BEGIN  
        SET NOCOUNT ON;  
        DECLARE @customerID NCHAR(50),  @lastpaymentDate DATETIME, @stat nchar(50), @month int;
        SET @customerID= (SELECT customerID FROM inserted)  
SET @stat= (SELECT stat FROM inserted) --table inserted contains inserted rows (or new updated rows)
        set @lastpaymentDate =  (SELECT MAX(paymentDate) FROM paymentReceipt where customerID=@customerID)  
    SET @month= (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,  @lastpaymentDate,GETDATE()))
     DECLARE @balance BIGINT
        SET @balance = 
                (
                    SELECT (totalprice-(paidAmount+concession)) 
                    FROM paymentData
                    WHERE customerID = @customerID
                )
                 Declare @paid int
                 SET @paid = 
                (
                    SELECT paidAmount 
                    FROM paymentData
                    WHERE customerID = @customerID
                )


        UPDATE PaymentData
            SET balanceAmount = @balance ,
              lastpaymentDate=@lastpaymentDate
        WHERE customerID = @customerID


    if (@month >=2  and @stat!='Cancel' and @stat!='Refund' And @stat!='Refunded' and @stat!='Transfered' and @stat!='Transfer')
    Begin

    IF  (@month <2 and @stat='Defaulter')
     SET @stat='Regular'
     IF (@balance<=0 and @paid >0)
     SET @stat='Payment Completed'
     else
     SET @stat='Defaulter'
     End
    else
    Begin

    if @stat='Refund'
     Set @stat='Refunded'
     if @stat='Cancled'
     Set @stat='Cancel'
     if @stat='Transfer'
     Set @stat='Transfered'
    End

     UPDATE PaymentData
            SET stat =@stat

        WHERE customerID = @customerID

    END
```

Comment: You even have the clue included in your question, as a comment: `table inserted contains inserted rows (or new updated rows)` - note it says *rows* - and yet you're attempting to select a *single* value out and assign it to a scalar variable.

Comment: This can probably be re-written as a set-based operation, or possible even replaced with computed columns and/or indexed views - but we'd need to have an idea on the table structures first - for instance, is there only ever one row in PaymentData for a particular `customerID`?

Comment: And finally (for now), I'd need to understand the logic of `IF (@month >=2 and ... begin ... if (@month < 2 and ...` - when will that second `if` statement ever be satisfied?

Comment: yes there is only one row in paymentData for a particular customerID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have a trigger at all. I'd rebuild your table and then create a view that mimics your current table definition. Of course, I don't know your current tables, so I can only write my best guess for now. And as I said, I don't understand your status logic at the bottom where `@month` can apparently be, simultaneously, both `>=2` and `<2`, so I've left that portion incomplete:

```
create table dbo._PaymentData (
    CustomerID nchar(50) not null,
    _Status nchar(50) not null,
    TotalPrice bigint not null,
    PaidAmount bigint not null,
    Concession bigint not null,
    Balance as TotalPrice - (PaidAmount + Concession)
)
go
create view dbo.PaymentData
with schemabinding
as
    with RecentReceipts as (
        select CustomerID,MAX(PaymentDate) as LastPayment from dbo.PaymentReceipt group by CustomerID
    ), MonthsDelinquent as (
        select CustomerID,LastPayment,DATEDIFF(month,LastPayment,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as Months from RecentReceipts
    )
    select
        pd.CustomerID,
        TotalPrice,
        PaidAmount,
        Concession,
        Balance,
        LastPayment,
        CASE
            WHEN _Status in ('Cancel','Refund','Refunded','Transfered','Transfer')
            THEN _Status
            WHEN md.Months > 2 and Balance<= 0 and PaidAmount > 0
            THEN 'Payment Complete'
            --More conditions here to work out the actual status
        END as Status
    from
        dbo._PaymentData pd
            left join
        MonthsDelinquent md
            on
                pd.CustomerID = md.CustomerID
go
```

And now, we don't *need* the trigger - the table and/or the view are always up correct (although a trigger *may* be required on the view to allow `Status`/`_Status` to be updated - it's not currently clear whether that's necessary or whether `_Status` actually needs to exist at all)

Answer (score 0):

Could their be more than one CustomerID added in the process?  This line is trouble:

```
   SET @customerID= (SELECT customerID FROM inserted)  
   SET @stat= (SELECT stat FROM inserted) --table inserted contains inserted
```

If customerID and stat are guaranteed to be consistent for all rows, you can fix it with a MAX, like:

```
   SET @customerID= (SELECT MAX(customerID) FROM inserted)  
   SET @stat= (SELECT MAX(stat) FROM inserted) --table inserted contains inserted
```

But, if those items aren't guaranteed to be consistent for all rows inserted, you will run into trouble.  If that's the case, you'll need a cursor to cursor through the values.

Also Change to this:

```
    SET @balance = 
            (
                SELECT SUM( (totalprice-(paidAmount+concession)) ) 
                FROM paymentData
                WHERE customerID = @customerID

            )
             Declare @paid int
             SET @paid = 
            (
                SELECT SUM(paidAmount) 
                FROM paymentData
                WHERE customerID = @customerID
            )
```

Comment: customerID is not constant. for example, for every customer only one record in paymentdata table but many records in the paymentreceipt table.

Comment: Ok, then you problem isn't with paymentData, so no need to do the SUM there.  What about in inserted?  SQL server would certainly let you insert multiple records for different customers, but do you have other business logic that would prevent this?  If so, then you can safely use a MAX, but to be really safe you might prefer a cursor.  Off topic, this kind of logic is better done outside of triggers, since triggers are more opaque and this is really your domain logic.  JMO